# Python generator function premature end exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

What exception should a Python generator function raise when it ends prematurely?

Context: searches of trees represented as classes with `__iter__` defined allowing code like `for i in BreadthFirstSearch(mytree)`.

These searches have a `max_depth` value after which the it should stop returning values.

What exception should be raised when this occurs, or should this be done some other way?

Comment: That sounds like a situation to just backtrack and continue on with the traversal, not to raise an exception or even notify the user at all.

Comment: As for the more general case of "oh no, something went wrong", raise whatever you would have raised in a normal function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StopIteration` is the proper exception to raise to stop an iteration entirely. However, `max_depth` shouldn't *stop* the traversal, the traversal should simply not recursively descend into child nodes when it's already at `max_depth` depth.

Comment: So what should the function do when it has yielded all the nodes up to max_depth depth?

Comment: Instead of descending into to the child nodes, simply continue to the next sibling. Which is the same thing you'd be doing after descending into the child nodes, so it's a simple `if` in front of your recursive call.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when *all* the nodes have been visited. Depth first search was probably a bad example.

Comment: When all the nodes have been visited, yeah, `StopException` is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer when the three minutes are up.

Comment: And then likely make a new question asking how to track depth in a depth first search!

Comment: Oh, that's easy! `def search(node, max_depth=None, cur_depth=0):` and then each recursive call passes `cur_depth+1` as the third parameter.

Comment: I'm sure it would be easy if done recursively, therein lies the problem! I'm sure when writing the algorithm I saw something on SO saying depth and breadth first searches were almost all implemented recursively, but now I seem to see the opposite... The non-recursive algorithm has the nice feature that it's the same for both breadth first and depth first, but with a queue for one and a stack for the other.

Comment: Then `len(stack)` is your depth.